# Valgrind reports lost memory blocks with multithreaded C program

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm building a program that takes files as input and shares them with N thread workers. The program works fine but when I run valgrind it gives me this memory leak alert:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==3907==     in use at exit: 128 bytes in 8 blocks
==3907==   total heap usage: 23,388 allocs, 23,380 frees, 707,078 bytes allocated
==3907== 
==3907== 128 bytes in 8 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3907==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3907==    by 0x10A9D2: threadWorker (main.c:66)
==3907==    by 0x49DBB42: start_thread (pthread_create.c:442)
==3907==    by 0x4A6CBB3: clone (clone.S:100)
==3907== 
==3907== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3907==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 8 blocks
==3907==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3907==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3907==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3907==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

the piece of code that the error is referring to

```
void *threadWorker(void *arg) {
    SyncQueue *sq = (SyncQueue *)arg;
    while (1) {
        SyncQueueAnswer *sqa = malloc(sizeof(SyncQueueAnswer));
        if (sqa == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        sqa->filedata = NULL;
        sqa->over = 0;
        dequeue(sq, &sqa);

        if (sqa->over == 1 || sqa->filedata == NULL) {
            free(sqa); // Free the memory allocated for sqa
            pthread_exit((void *)1);
        } else {
            calculateFileData(sqa->filedata);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&send_mutex);
            if (sendThroughSocket(sqa->filedata, sq->sockfd) < 0) {
                perror("Error while sending data from thread");
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&send_mutex);

            free(sqa->filedata->vector);
            free(sqa->filedata);
        }
        free(sqa);
    }
}
```

for reference, the code above starts at line 63.

When I increase the number of files also the number of lost blocks increases. Reading valgrind it looks like the problem is
`SyncQueueAnswer *sqa = malloc(sizeof(SyncQueueAnswer));`
but, as far as I can tell, the memory is being freed after the use. Am I missing Something?

Comment: the one thing that stands out and looks a bit suspicious is where you call dequeue with the address of sqa which points to the newly allocated SyncQueueAnswer. I don't know what that dequeue function does, but if it changes the pointer, then there will be a memory leak.

Comment: Yes @AndersK has the likely issue. You can verify it by surrounding the `dequeue` with a check. Something like `SyncQueueAnswer *savedsqa = sqa; dequeue(sq, &sqa); assert(savedsqa == sqa);`. Almost certainly you'll see the assertion fail.

Comment: Yes, the problem was a reallocation inside the dequeue function. Thanks fro the feedback!